# Disallow 'Preview' Windows 10 Updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows is suggesting preview updates even though I am not participating in the Windows Insider Program. Is there a way I can stop Windows from suggesting these updates?

[image: windows update screenshot]

Comment: if you wait for updates to come you get the updates when they are released, but if you click the 'check for updates' button, you may get previews of tested updates one month early. It's nothing to do with the Insider Program. They only changed the name to add 'preview' recently (2020) so you've probably been getting them for years.

Comment: Please kindly check if this article was helpful to you: [Stop receiving insider builds for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/stop-receiving-insider-builds-for-windows-10-be2c37cf-ae6e-c654-a6df-b3ebbcdc3404)

Comment: @Sunny - he or she is not on the Insider Program.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want them, don't click 'Check for Updates' in Windows Update. An Optional Quality Update is is a Windows update that you got early because you clicked 'Check for Updates'. If you had not done that, you would be getting it on next month's Patch Tuesday. It's nothing to do with the Insider Program. They only changed the name to add 'preview' recently (2020) so you've probably been getting them for years.

The idea is that if you clicked to check for updates, you are an interested user and Microsoft gets you to test the update for a couple of weeks before they roll it out. Microsoft calls people who visit the Windows Update page and choose to manually install updates “seekers” who are looking for updates.

Comment: In this case it's not me who is clicking 'check for updates', but inexperienced computer users who are paranoid about ensuring everything is up to date. I want to avoid having them install any preview or pre-release updates to avoid unneeded stability problems (and unwanted phone calls for me to fix it).  Do you have any sources from Microsoft about these 'seeker' updates?

Comment: @ecnepsnai   Not at Microsoft, but here are details about disabling the check for updates button by Group Policy or a Registry key https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65013-enable-disable-check-windows-updates-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @ecnepsnai See here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-update#update-setdisableuxwuaccess

Comment: @ecnepsnai - discussion of the the Windows 10 update cadence, including C and D updates ("Cumulative Update Previews). https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/windows-10-update-servicing-cadence/ba-p/222376